# Resize height of Infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps, location, infowindow

I have a Google map which is showing the current location and place name in InfoWindow. It's working well, but the problem is when the Place name is too long, at that time, the whole text is not showing properly in InfoWindow like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTtpA.png). How can I resize this Infowindow?
  My code is below:

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        private View view;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);

            view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if (CheckIn.this.marker != null && CheckIn.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                CheckIn.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                CheckIn.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
            CheckIn.this.marker = marker;

            String url = null, isLoaded = "0";

            /*if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                if (markers.get(marker.getId()) != null && markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                    url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                    isLoaded = markers.get(marker.getId() + marker.getTitle());
                }
            }*/
            final ImageView imgAddress = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAddress));

            final String title = marker.getTitle();

            final CustomTextView txtTitle = ((CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle));
            if (title != null) {
                /*txtTitle.setText("La Brasserie Bordelaise");*/
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                txtTitle.setText(currentPlaceName);
                txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(CheckIn.this, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                txtTitle.setText("");
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
```

my xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customFont="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_120"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_30"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_30"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_info_window">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgAddress">

                <com.widget.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="aaaa"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
                    customFont:fontTextStyle="3" />
                <!--android:text="La Brasserie Bordelaise"-->


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_person" />

                    <com.widget.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTotalPeople"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="aaaa"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorDetailGray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                        customFont:fontTextStyle="3" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set a static width for the whole layout.

**Solution 1**

Change

```
view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

To

```
view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**Solution 2**

Make the textView multiline by setting maxLines as 2 or 3
like `txtTitle.setMaxLines(2)`

Comment: My info_window layout contain 2 TextViews So second textview showing out of InfoWindow!!!

Comment: Can you post an image as I can't try this right now ? Post a screen and state the id for it.

Comment: Can you also post the xml of info_window

Comment: Change the relative layout height from margin_120 to wrap_content